# Web scraping web dinámica con Selenium y captar código HTML final con Beautiful Soup

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, scraping, beautifulsoup

Hace días que me rompo la cabeza con este problema, estoy realizando web scraping de un buscador de jurisprudencia, como es una web dinámica utilizo Selenium para que ajuste los filtros realice la busqueda y quiero acceder dentro de los links resultantes para extraer del código HTML cual es el source del PDF que hay integrado en la página final. Consigo llegar hasta la página pero cuando solicito el código HTML de esta me devuelve un HTML que no coincide con el de la página (seguramente el de la busqueda antes de entrar al link final.

Adjunto el código que tengo desarrollado hasta el momento. Si alguien tiene alguna suposición de lo que me puede estar pasando le estaré muy agradecido!!

```html
PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
options.add_argument('--incognito')
options.add_argument('--headless')
      
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

# Enter to CENDOJ web page
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
driver.get('https://www.poderjudicial.es/search/indexAN.jsp')
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"button.close"))).click()

# Jurisdicción Civil
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"(//button[@class='multiselect dropdown-toggle btn btn-default tooltips'])[1]"))).click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//label[.//input[@value='CIVIL']]"))).click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"(//button[@class='multiselect dropdown-toggle btn btn-default tooltips'])[1]"))).click()

# Tipo de órgano Audiencia Provincial
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"(//button[@class='multiselect dropdown-toggle btn btn-default tooltips'])[2]"))).click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//label[.//input[@value='37']]"))).click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"(//button[@class='multiselect dropdown-toggle btn btn-default tooltips'])[2]"))).click()

# Localización Cataluña
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"(//button[@id='COMUNIDADmultiselec'])"))).click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//label[.//input[@id='chkCOM_CATALUÑA']]"))).click()

# Buscamos por la temática de interes
search = driver.find_element_by_id("frmBusquedajurisprudencia_TEXT")
search.send_keys("deshaucio")
search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

# Seleccionamos primer link y entramos
text = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "jurisprudenciaresults_searchresults")))
#Enter the first link
link = text.find_element_by_class_name('title').click()

#Final webpage I want to extract the PDF source

driver.implicitly_wait(10)
el = driver.find_element_by_id("content")
# Error: not finding the element...

# Final step collecting HTML code
# page_source = driver.page_source
# soup = BeautifulSoup(page_source, 'lxml')
# print(soup.prettify())
```